# CakePHP 2.x fields list shows list of id's instead of values

Tags: cakephp-2.0

In my PartsController I have the following code:

```
$serialNrs = $this->Part->find('list',
        array(
        'conditions'=>array(
            'Part.status_id' => 3
        ),
        'fields'=> array('serial_nr_id' )
        //'fields'=> array('serialNr.name')
    ));
```

The according select field shows a list of id's instead of values.
When I use `'fields'=> array('serialNr.name')` I get an error:

### SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'SerialNr.name' in 'field list'

SELECT `Part`.`serial_nr_id`, `SerialNr`.`name` FROM `part145`.`parts` AS `Part` WHERE `Part`.`status_id` = 3

What do I need to do to show a list of values?

Comment: add two fields `'fields'=> array('serial_nr_id' , 'value or title that you want to show')`

Comment: That would be serialNr.name but it throws an error.

Comment: if your database column name is `serialNr.name` than it will give error because cakephp will take it as model name, change it to `serial_nr_name` and if this is your model name then you can not add column from another table in `list` function.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Model name instead of the actual table name in database, thus

```
$serialNrs = $this->Part->find('list',
    array(
    'conditions'=>array(
        'Part.status_id' => 3
    ),
    'fields'=> array('Part.name' )
));
```

According to the above code, you have a model named "Part" where it points to a database table where there are at least a "status_id" column and a "name" column.